# Flexbox items 4 per row instead of 2?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Whenever I try to set up flex items this way, instead of getting 2 per row I am getting 4. But with the second solution it seems to work properly. Why it wont work as it is in first css code?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 0.5;
}
```

Second:

```cs
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  flex: 50%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having display flex, plus flex-wrap property. It will occupy space based on the available space left to be covered.

Coming back to your question, flex is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis. so having 0.5 will not be equal to 50%.

To understand more about the flex properties look at this for your [references](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp).

I usually opt for grid, when I need to show a particular amount of elements on a certain situation.

We can change the display from flex to grid:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional. The default is 0 1 auto, but if you set it with a single number value, like flex: 5;, that changes the flex-basis to 0%, so it’s like setting flex-grow: 5; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0%;.
Flex-grow is scalable. But if you want to scale the width as a percentage. Then you should use the percent sign to allow you to scale the width.
This code is similar to:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```